# Liquid ignoring _config.yml infos for jekyll theme

Tags: themes, jekyll, liquid

I'm new to **jekyll**, I read the infos from their website and did the basic stuff and all worked ok. Now, I'm trying to learn more by doing a theme to it. The idea is I got a html template and I'm trying to make it to jekyll. The repo is at [prologue-like-jekyll-theme](https://github.com/mhadaniya/prologue-like-jekyll-theme).

I have a **_config.yml** with some info:

```
# Site settings
title: Personal Jekyll theme based on Prologue by HTML5 UP.
description: "Write your site description here."
baseurl: ""
url: ""
avatar: images/avatar.png
email: your-email@yourdomain.com
copyright_name: Your/Project/Corporate Name
```

I did a **default.html** layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>{{ site.title }}</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Header -->
        {% include header.html %}

    <!-- Main -->
    <div id="main">
        {{ content }}
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    {% include footer.html %}

    </body>
</html>
```

I execute `jekyll server`, it runs but the `site.title` is not loading. The funny thing is if I change to `site.time` it works. Don't know why this is happen, any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_config.yml` file is in `_layouts` folder, it should be in the root folder.

Comment: thanks for you time and reply! I didn't realize that I created the `_config.yml` into the `_layout` folder and not in the root!